# What does "head up" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Treasure Island:

> He continued. “I'm a plain man; rum and bacon and eggs is what I want, and **that head up there for** to watch ships off. What you mought call me? You mought call me captain. Oh, I see what you're at - there”

The bold part confuses me. What does "*head up*" mean in this context? What does "*that*" stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is colloquial and dialectal—literally "Talk like a pirate"—and somewhat antiquated—the story is set in the 18th century. The 'captain' wants

> *that* — a demonstrative, pointing to a specific
>   *head* — [headland](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/headland), a protruding stretch of the cliffs
>   *up there* — located at a specific point farther along the road and above the sea
>   *for* — in order
>   *to watch ships* — to survey traffic on the sea below
>   *off* — from it

Comment: Is 'for' redundant here? I think it relates to 'want', but 'and that head up there' splits them.

Comment: @KinzleB *For to VERB* is an obsolete construction indicating the purpose *for* which he wants the head. In ModE we'd use a gerund (*for watching*). Moreover, the marked infinitive by itself indicates purpose, so it doesn't strictly "need" this indicator; but then it doesn't "need" the perfectly acceptable *in order* ('in order to watch'), either.

Comment: I run into all sorts of weird expressions in old-fashioned novels. Sometimes I feel I'm reading a different language. BTW, I would interpret 'watch ships off' to mean 'watch ships leave'. Why is that ruled out?

Comment: @KinzleB It's not 'ruled out', but the natural parse is that *off* is a stranded preposition in a covert relative modifying *head*: "off which to watch ships"